# Solve equations with multiple variables (Python)

Tags: python, equation

I have an equation, say `x = .5 (b + c) - d`. I would like to solve this equation for all of the variables. For example, `d = …` or `b =`. This would mean that the variables are equal to other variables.

Another example is this simple equation: `x = b/c`. C is equal to `b/x` and `b = c * x` (please correct my math if it’s wrong). Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: see here : https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/10-Symbolic-Math/10.06-Solving-Equations/

Comment: Problably this library will help: https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g. :

```
from sympy import symbols, solve, Eq 

x = symbols('x')
b = symbols('b')
c = symbols('c')
d = symbols('d')

eq1 = Eq(x, 0.5*(b+c)-d)

sol_d = solve(eq1, d)
sol_b = solve(eq1, b)

print(sol_d, sol_b)
```

Output: `[0.5*b + 0.5*c - x] [-c + 2.0*d + 2.0*x]`

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0Tj2ausMBI) and [explanation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) of the solve() command